# MS Visual Studio, #C, FORM, Server to User: splitting received data into different textboxes

Tags: c#, forms, api, visual-studio-2013, broadcast

I'm trying to split send data into different display boxes and I'm having hard time..

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013 and Networks API library.

Server-side program code is following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    server.BroadCast(textBox2.Text);
}
```

Whatever is in textBox2 is BroadCasted to client-side program (to everyone who is connected)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    server.SendTo((string)listBox1.SelectedItem, textBox2.Text);
}
```

Private message to chosen user.. but here is my problem:

In Client-side program anything what is received will be displayed in one same box and I want to split it; private messages into own box and broadcasted messages to its own..

currently I have following code:

```
void Chatprojekti_OnDataReceived(object Sender, ClientReceivedArguments R)
{
    ChangeTextBox(R.ReceivedData);   
}

private void ChangeTextBox(string txt) // Chatlog update
{

    if(textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new UpdateText(ChangeTextBox), new object[] { txt });
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text += txt + "\r\n";

    }
}
```

I don't have any ideas how to do it, but hopefully some of you can give me tip how to do it, Thanks! :)